Flutter Android Studio emulator glitching
Glitching simulator
any idea to fix this problem without disabling hw.gpu.enabled = no and hw.gpu.mode = off
my curremt pc spec
Proc: i5-12400f
VGA: AMD Radeon RX 6650 XT
Ram: 32gb
I am trying to check another fixed for this answer, because I got performance issue if I disable GPU mode

Glitching simulator without disable GPU mode in flutter.
The glitching issue on Android Emulator due to conflict between flutter's rendering engine. Disabling hardware GPU is one of opitions. But its affect overall performance
Here are steps for solve the issue.

Step No 1 : Modify Emulator Graphics Setting.

Open AVD Manager in Android Studio.
Select your emulator and click edit.
Under emulator performance inside Graphics select OpenGL.
Save the setting or restart you emulator.


Step No 2 : Run Emulator OpenGL using command line for launch emulator.

flutter emulators --launch <emulator-id> -gpu guest.



Why this will works without disabling GPU.
Forcing OpenGL or impeller compatibility with AVD GPU's.
Tell me if this resolve your issue or you need more additional debugging.

